# Deploy a Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

i would like to deploy my ruby on rails website. I am using rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3, so have the assets pipeline feature. What i would like to know is who offers the most complete hosting package ( or easiest as I am new to rails). I don't mind paying for a package or trying a free one, just as long as its idiot proof :).

Any advice helpful as I would like to get this uploaded for a client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is pretty much today's standard for deploying Rails app, if you are into paying for it.

I would personally recommend to deploy in your own server if possible. It's much more versatile and not difficult at all. You could also make the procedure more efficient by using a tool like capistrano, which i highly recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. will look into getting my own server. Any advice for documentation to read to help with this process?

Comment: this one is a great resource : http://www.mirceagoia.com/downloads/Installation_Ruby-on-Rails_for_Ubuntu-Linux-Mint_www-mirceagoia-com.pdf